# Getting an empty json entity and can't persist in runtime with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm writing my first CRUD as Spring Boot application. Now I'm facing the problem that i somehow get an empty entity in my response array and also can't add another entity.

I have a classic MVC structure where I have a resource class which provides the resources for a frontend (GET and POST at the time), a service class (which actually just bypasses the data), a controller class which provides the objects and sets up a test object.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/genesysAgents")
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = GenesysService.class)
public class GenesysAgentResource {

    @Autowired
    private GenesysService genesysService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<GenesysAgent> getAllGenesysAgents() { return genesysService.getAllGenesysAgents();}


    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> addGenesysAgent(GenesysAgent genesysAgent) {
        genesysService.addGenesysAgent(genesysAgent);
        return new ResponseEntity<GenesysAgent>(genesysAgent, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = GenesysController.class)
public class GenesysService {

    @Autowired
    private GenesysController genesysController;    

    private static final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(10);

    @Bean
    public List<GenesysAgent> getAllGenesysAgents() {
        return genesysController.getAgents();
    }

    @Bean
    public GenesysAgent addGenesysAgent(GenesysAgent genesysAgent) {
        genesysAgent.setId(id.getAndIncrement());
        genesysController.addAgent(genesysAgent);
        return genesysAgent;
    }
```

```
@Component
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = GenesysAgent.class)
public class GenesysController {

        List<GenesysAgent> genesysAgents = new ArrayList<GenesysAgent>();

        public GenesysController(){
        GenesysAgent agent1 = new GenesysAgent();
        agent1.setId(0);
        agent1.setFirstName("Max");
        agent1.setLastName("Muster");
        agent1.setNtAccount("testAccount");
        genesysAgents.add(agent1);
        }

    @Bean
    public List<GenesysAgent> getAgents(){
        return genesysAgents;
    }

    @Bean
    public GenesysAgent addAgent(GenesysAgent genesysAgent){
        genesysAgents.add(genesysAgent);

        return genesysAgent;
    }
```

When i now run the Application and do a GET i get:

[
    {
        "id": 0,
        "firstName": "Max",
        "lastName": "Muster",
        "ntAccount": "testAccount"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "firstName": null,
        "lastName": null,
        "ntAccount": null
    }
]

I can't explain where the secound entry comes from.
Also wenn i do a POST with the following Data:

{
    "firstName": "Max",
    "lastName": "Muster",
    "ntAccount": "test"
}

I get a 201 but the response is:

{
    "id": 0,
    "firstName": null,
    "lastName": null,
    "ntAccount": null
}

Comment: You seem to be using annotations randomly. Remove all those COmponentScan, COnfiguration and Bean annotations. And `genesysAgent`, in your controller (the actual controller, not the class you named Controller but is actually not a controller),  must be annotated with RequestBody.

Comment: I'm not sure if i get your right. I tried it without those Annotations before. The server then told me that he needs to have Beans in the GenesysService to run correct. If i remove those Annotations this problem happens again to to the Autowired annotation, which i use as alternative to an Inject.
The class that isnt a controller will later on be a controller to get Data from another API. I know its kinda confusing at that point.

Comment: This is way too broad. Read the Spring documentation to understand the responsibility of the various classes and the meaning of the annotations. A controller is just that: a controller which answers to HTTP requests. It's annotated with RestController and RequestMapping. A configuration class is just that: it configures the application by telling which packages to scan (although that is generally unnecessary) and by providing beans to the application. It's annotated with Configuration and has `@Bean` methods.

Comment: A service is just that: a class providing services to other beans (to controllers, for example). It's annotated with Component or Service. You're mixing everything everywhere, and use incorrect names, too.